# character of a representation of the group $S_n$

Tags: abstract-algebra, finite-groups, representation-theory

> Let $\Phi$ be a representation of the group $S_n$ in the space 
>   with basis $(e_1, \ldots, e_n)$ such that $\Phi(\sigma)e_i=e_{\sigma(i)}.$ Find character of  $\Phi$

This is looks like a regular representation. I have no idea how to start it

There is  answer in my book: " $\chi(\Phi)$ is the number of elements of the set {1, 2, 3, ..., n} what are fixed with respect to $\sigma$

Comment: Can you show that the matrix of $\Phi(\sigma)=(a_{ij})$ with $a_{ij}=1$, if $i=\sigma(j)$, and $a_{ij}=0$ otherwise? Then compute the trace $\sum_i a_{ii}$? It isn't the regular representation. But it is a very natural representation of $S_n$ and often goes by that name.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, I call this the *permutation representation*.  (The *regular* representation refers to the group $S_n$ acting on itself by left multiplication.  It is $n!$ dimensional.)

Since you have chosen a basis, you can think of the representation as a group homomorphism
$$
\Phi: S_n \to GL(n).
$$
The character $\chi$ of the representation is the composition
$$
\chi = \operatorname{tr} \circ \Phi:  S_n \to k,
$$
where $k$ is the ground field.  Since the trace function sums the diagonal entries of the matrix, and $\Phi(\sigma)$ is a matrix consisting of a single $1$ in each row and each column with zeroes elsewhere, $\chi(\sigma)$ counts the number of $j$ such that $\sigma(j) = j$.  In that case (and only in that case) does $\Phi(\sigma)(e_j) = e_{\sigma(j)} = e_j$.

By the way, this representation contains a copy of the trivial $1$ dimensional representation with basis $e_1 + \cdots + e_n$, whose complement is the $n - 1$ dimensional *standard* representation on the basis $\{ e_1 - e_2, e_2 - e_3, \ldots, e_{n-1} - e_n \}$.